# How to create class with every Property as Static?

Tags: c#, properties, static-class

i have created Solution which contain 3 Projects like.

```
//Project Name: ClientProject
    public class UserDetails
    {
        public static int ID { get; set; }
        public static string Name { get; set; }
        public static string Email { get; set; }
    }
```

**This above class should be set once, When user logged in and after that i would like to access these details across entire solution.**

Like Administration, SalesInfo projects.

```
//Project Name: Administration
    public class Admin
    {
        public static UserDetails Details
        {
            //Here i would like to return UserDetails
            get; 
        }
        public static int DepartmentID { get; set; }
        public static string Phone { get; set; }
        public static string Head { get; set; }
    }

    //Project Name: SalesInfo
    public class Sales
    {
        public static UserDetails Details
        {
            //Here i would like to return UserDetails
            get;
        }
        public static DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public static string Item { get; set; }
        public static int Price { get; set; }
    }
```

Any Answer, Comments or Suggestions would be highly appreciated

Comment: Is this a web app? Win forms? WPF? Should the information be accessible to everyone or is this "per user"? Have you looked at design patterns?

Comment: This is a very bad design decision. Hard to test and impossible to extend using OOP mechanisms. If you want a single instance of your class, look up Singleton pattern, but do make your class members instance. And from your question I presume by `static`, you actually mean **read-only**?

Comment: You can use a static constructor.

Comment: 1. You have non-static classes with entirely static members. 2. You don't need to expose `UserDetails` as a static property on these other classes -- it's already globally accessible, just access it where needed as `UserDetails.Name` &c.

Comment: This is a terrible terrible idea...

Answer (score 1):

Normally property uses private field to store the data. This behavior added during compile time and is hidden for the developer while coding. Static method/property can't access private variables/fields in a class.

I recommend to use singleton pattern.

```
public class UserDetails
{
    private static UserDetails _instance;

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }

    private UserDetails() {}

    public static UserDetails Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (_instance == null)
            {
                 _instance = new UserDetails();
            }
            return _instance;
        }
    }
}
```

And you can consume like this,

```
//Project Name: Administration
public class Admin
{
    public static UserDetails Details
    {
        get
        {
            return UserDetails.Instance;
        } 
    }
    public static int DepartmentID { get; set; }
    public static string Phone { get; set; }
    public static string Head { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, my vote of +1, Please see following http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9667931/static-class-property-getting-null-when-custom-validation-fired-in-silverlight-4

Answer (score 1):

Use a kind of singleton as mentioned by Groo.

```
public class UserDetails
{
  public static int ID { get; private set; }
  public static string Name { get; private set; }
  public static string Email { get; private set; }

  private static UserDetails _userDetails;

  private UserDetails(int id, string name, string email)
  {
    ID = id;
    Name = name;
    Email = email;
  }

  public static UserDetails CreateUserDetails(int id, string name, string email)
  {
    if (_userDetails != null)
    {
      throw new MyException("Second call to UserDetails.CreateUserDetails!");
    }
    _userDetails = new UserDetails(id, name, email);

    return _userDetails;
  }

  public static UserDetails GetUserDetails()
  {
    if (_userDetails == null)
    {
      throw new MyException("Not yet created by calling UserDetails.CreateUserDetails!");
    }

    return _userDetails;
  }
```

}

After log-in you call `UserDetails.CreateUserDetails(...)` to set the global object.
To get details call `GetUserDetails()`.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable answer but my problem is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9667931/static-class-property-getting-null-when-custom-validation-fired-in-silverlight-4

Comment: Sorry I'm not a Silverlight expert.